# Microsoft Graph /users/<id>/events/ doesn't return event body

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a valid integration with Microsoft Graph, however the body of the meeting invite is always returned as a blank string. In addition, the "subject" param is always filed in with the name of the meeting organizer, not the meeting subject. Find the (anonymized) returned body below. I'm curious if I'm misunderstanding the API spec before I file an issue with Microsoft.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('codingconferenceroom%40foo.onmicrosoft.com')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"0WG02jiCr0KWGp+LyVIbbQAAAGI7qw==\"",
    "id": "AAMkAGVhNjY4ODEzLTczNzMtNDA4Ny04ZDRhLTQzM2ZjYjBkNjJjZQBGAAAAAABkfHRPWtE1SJSESH8oJuShBwDRYbTaOIKvQpYan4vJUhttAAAAAAENAADRYbTaOIKvQpYan4vJUhttAAAAYhFcAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2016-10-18T16:06:26.7490468Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-10-18T16:06:33.1931576Z",
    "changeKey": "0WG02jiCr0KWGp+LyVIbbQAAAGI7qw==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "accepted",
        "time": "2016-10-18T16:06:26.9432002Z"
    },
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000028DB2E925929D2010000000000000000100000007CED5B09FC262149A6E0A253EF628393",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "API user",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": ""
    },
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2016-10-18T21:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2016-10-18T22:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "My Fun Conference Room",
        "address": {
            "street": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "countryOrRegion": "",
            "postalCode": ""
        }
    },
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": false,
    "recurrence": null,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "attendees": [
        {
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "type": "required",
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "API user",
                "address": "user@foo.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "API user",
            "address": "user@foo.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    },
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null
}
```

Comment: I see that this event is coming from a room resource calendar. Are you seeing the same lack of body property value for regular user attendees?

Comment: @MichaelMainer-MSFT No, this is specific to room resources. Is this a known issue, or an intentional limitation?

Comment: Just clarifying the scenario, are you looking to return a collection of meetings scheduled for a given room?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I'd like to query a given rooms schedule, so a collection would be returned. The issue at hand is that neither the body of the meeting invite, nor the proper meeting subject is returned when the param is a room resource type instead of a human.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Any further word on this? Is there any plan to allow me to query a room's schedule?

Comment: Is this pretty much a mail enabled group? if so have you tried using "groups/YourGroupId/events"

Comment: i know this is old question, but i have the exact problem, did you find any reason or solution for empty body content?

Comment: @mehdok I know this is old comment, but I've added one answer bellow anyway. Hope it's still be helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been working on a similar applications i.e. fetching calendar events using resource's (room) userPrincipalName via Microsoft Graph API and I had the same problem. I contacted Microsoft Tech Support and they suggested me this link which might help you.
[Resource mailbox's calendar shows the organizer's name instead of the subject in an Exchange Server environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2842288/resource-mailbox-s-calendar-shows-the-organizer-s-name-instead-of-the)

In addition, keep in mind another problem that I had. In my app, I wanted to see if any updates happened to attendees list i.e. if anybody accepted or declined invitation, or somebody was removed from the list completely. However, using room's userPrincipalName it's not visible. Your attendees list will remain the same regardless of changes. 
According the product design the only way to see responseStatus changes is when an attendee send's an email. Resource's mailboxes are not receiving any of these emails, hence it's not visible. Moreover, if an attendee decides to change status without sending an email it won't be visible from any userPrincipalName other then, attendee's.

Comment: Do we know if this is still the case in 2023?